# RecyclerviewAdapter code not working in android

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

How to load multiple datasets as object using recycler view adapter ? I have tried using the examples but I am getting cast related error. can anyone help ?
this is the code for the activity from where I am populating the data and calling the adapter -

```
package com.example.aniketmondal.aniskitchen;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
public class OrderPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    private  FoodAdapter adapter;
    private Query query;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_page);
        setUpRecyclerView();
    }
    private void setUpRecyclerView() {
        query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/Food/Mughlai");
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Food> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Food>().setQuery(query, Food.class).build();
        adapter = new FoodAdapter(options);
        RecyclerView rcview = findViewById(R.id.post_rv);
        rcview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rcview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        rcview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact and complete error message and stack trace you get.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting up your `RecyclerView` on the `onCreate` method. Most importantly, however, your adapter is calling the `startListening()` method which you did not override from the parent class. So, you could rename your `setUpRecyclerView()` to `startListening`. And you don't need to call it from the onCreate if you setup your `RecyclerView` there. It would look something like this...

```
package com.example.aniketmondal.aniskitchen;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

public class OrderPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    private  FoodAdapter adapter;
    private Query query;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_page);
        RecyclerView rcview = findViewById(R.id.post_rv);
        rcview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rcview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
    @Override
    private void startListening() {
        query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/Food/Mughlai");
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Food> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Food>().setQuery(query, Food.class).build();
        adapter = new FoodAdapter(options);          
        rcview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the listener in `onStart` you have to remove it in `onStop`.

If you have added the listener in `onResume` you have to remove it in `onPause`.

If you have added the listener in `onCreate` you have to remove it in `onDestroy`. But remember onDestroy is not always called.